# Label position according to button position dynamically

Tags: html, css, angular, dynamic, label

I'm working on an interface that allows user to change the button position and writing a label text under the button.
My problem is, the label is not all the time centering under the buttons, it depends on the size and number of letters of the text label,

this is my css classes

```css
    .button-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 80px;
    text-align: center;}


    .button-wrapper > button {
    display: block;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    text-align: center;
    :active  {border: 3px solid yellow;}
    :hover{border: 2px solid red;}}

    .button-wrapper > label {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin:0 auto; left:0; right:0;
    padding: 3px;}
```

And this is my html code

```html
     <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button
                [class.btn-primary]="true"
                [style.color]="buttonStyle.labeLFontColor"
                [ngStyle]="{'margin-left': bar.accessPosition+'%','font-style': buttonStyle.labeLFontFamily, 'font-size.px':buttonStyle.labeLFontSize, 'font-weight':buttonStyle.labeLFontWeight,
                'background-color': buttonStyle.backgroundColor, 'font-family': buttonStyle.labeLFontFamily, 'border-color': buttonStyle.borderColor,
                     'border': buttonStyle.borderSize+'px solid', 'background':'url(assets/showcase/images/accessButtons/' + bar.accessBackImage+') white center center no-repeat',
                 'background-size': '100% 75px'}">
        </button>
        <label  *ngIf="useLabel"  [ngStyle]="{'margin-left': bar.accessPosition+'%','font-style': buttonStyle.labeLFontFamily, 'font-size.px':buttonStyle.labeLFontSize, 'font-weight':buttonStyle.labeLFontWeight,'font-family': buttonStyle.labeLFontFamily }">{{accessLabel}}</label>
    </div>
```

As you see everything is dynamic the label size, the label text also I have an input to write the text...
So how can I fix the label to be always centering and below whatever the user writes.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you share a Stackblitz example?

Comment: sure, this is a stackblitz link : https://angular-ivy-xq4wal.stackblitz.io/

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xq4wal?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [stacblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xq4wal?file=src/app/app.component.ts) you provided, the following CSS may be what you are trying to achieve (just replace your CSS with this):

```
.button-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
}

.button-wrapper > button {
  display: block;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.button-wrapper > button:hover {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.button-wrapper > button:focus {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
}

.button-wrapper > label {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

**Notes:**

- Some of your CSS was badly structured
- For any layout and positioning, consider [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Answer (score 0):

Trick to these kinds of things is to isolate the things you want to work and display together and wrap them up.

In this case, button + label, nicely wrapped up in a div.

That outer div is then what you concern yourself with when it comes to putting together your page as a whole. The page level should concern itself with where that group of things goes, not where each of those individual parts go.

That said, here's a forked [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uka2f8?file=src/app/app.component.css) showing what you presumably want.

`button-wrapper` is the the outside div you want to handle positioning on your screen (you said the user can move it?).

However, your button and label are just isolated (one might even say encapsulated) items in there that are now laid out in a centered fashion. It's reduced the issue down to simply where you put your `button-wrapper` div on your page. Wherever it goes, the button and label, at least, will both be centered within it.